# How to encode and decode foreign charset when scraping data using php DOMDocument Class

Tags: php

Here is an example string that I am trying to scrape

```
  Les Meilleurs Hôtels de Normandie en 2015
```

When I scrape it, I get a utf8 encoding on it as follows

```
  Les Meilleurs HÃ´tels de Normandie en 2015
```

To convert it back, I use following function

```
  mb_convert_encoding($utf8_string, 'Windows-1252', 'UTF-8');
```

The above function works but I was wondering if it possible to circumvent this conversion process and scrape the string as is?